# How to continuously change background image of a div using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have 5 jpg images in my image folder. I want a div to change background one by one automatically. How to do this using jQuery?

I can manipulate the background property using jQuery once but I am stuck when I try to automatically change and loop.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".topstrip").css('background-image', 'url("/static/img/website/banner/factory_plane-normal.jpg")')
});
```

Comment: And what did you try? Show the code for us.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use setInterval function. Sample Code.

```
                $(document).ready(function () {
                var imageFile = ["Image.jpg", "Image1.jpg", "Image2.jpg", "Image4.jpg"];
                var currentIndex = 0;
                setInterval(function () {
                    if (currentIndex == imageFile.length) {
                        currentIndex = 0;
                    }
                    $(".topstrip").css('background-image', 'url("/static/img/website/banner/' + imageFile[currentIndex++] + '")');
                }, 3000);
            });
```

Comment: Looks really clean. But only First image is displayed. Indexing missed?

Comment: Works great. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="topstrip" style="height:100px;width:100px;"></div>

    <script>
    var imagebackground = 0;
    var imgbackgrounds = [];
    imgbackgrounds[0] ='/images/image1.jpg';
    imgbackgrounds[1] ='/images/image2.jpg';
    imgbackgrounds[2] ='/images/image3.jpg';
    imgbackgrounds[3] ='/images/image4.jpg';
    imgbackgrounds[4] ='/images/image5.jpg';


    function changeimage() {
        imagebackground++;
        if(imagebackground > 4) imagebackground = 0;

        $('.topstrip').fadeToggle("slow",function() {
            $('.topstrip').css({
                'background-image' : "url('" + imgbackgrounds[imagebackground] + "')"
            });
            $('.topstrip').fadeToggle("slow");
        });  


        setTimeout(changeimage, 5000);
    }  

    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(changeimage, 5000);        
    });  
    </script>
```